# How to get stty echo mode from xterm.js?

Tags: xtermjs, stty

I'd like to be able to tell when echo mode is turned off in xterm.js (for example, when entering a password).  stty can report and change that information, but (obviously) can't be executed while waiting for a user to enter a password. What is the API for querying the echo state?

Comment: The API for that is called termios with functions like tcgetattr or tcsetattr (see https://linux.die.net/man/3/tcgetattr).

Comment: Add your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The terminal metrics as seen under linux, macos and other POSIX compatible operating systems is a POSIX feature specified under terminal interface section:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX_terminal_interface
- https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/basedefs/xbd_chap11.html

The interesting part for many settings around a terminal, like ECHO mode, is the `termios` API, which you can access with `tcgetattr` / `tcsetattr` in C on a compliant system. Furthermore many languages provide some sort of bindings to that API (e.g. the python module `termios`).

The documentation can be accessed on most POSIX systems by either calling `man termios` or `man tcgetattr`.

Example docs from the web:

- [FreeBSD termios](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=termios&sektion=4)
- [Linux tcgetattr](https://linux.die.net/man/3/tcgetattr)

**Edit:**

Re-reading your question - if you want to able to grab the ECHO state from xterm.js, well that is not possible that easy. The reason for this is cumbersome - xterm.js is an emulator behind a PTY. A PTY splits the terminal actions in a master and a slave part, where the master part acts as the terminal process (xterm.js here) and the slave part is a process attached to that terminal. While POSIX only guarantees, that the `termios` API works on the slave part (its whole writeup was meant for consuming processes), BSD-flavored systems also allow `termios` semantics on the master part.

**TL;DR:** On linux and macos you can use `termios` API on the master *file descriptor* held by your PTY-binding (e.g. `node-pty`), while this will only work on the slave *file descriptor* under solaris clones (or any other STREAMS based TTY implementations).